# Sitecore on Azure PaaS solution

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1, sitecore-azure

I have these following queries related to  continuing to  utilize Sitecore as our WCM solution and migrating to the Sitecore on Azure PaaS solution.

1.What are the Pros of continuing to utilize Sitecore as our WCM solution?

2.What are the Cons of continuing to utilize Sitecore as our WCM solution?

3.What are the Pros of migrating to the Sitecore on Azure PaaS solution?

4.What are the Cons of migrating to the Sitecore on Azure PaaS solution?

Please help me in understanding these.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1. What are the pros of continuing to utilize Sitecore as our WCM solution?

Sitecore is perfect for an organization that needs the ability to perform a lot of customizations to their website and the data that is exposed there. It allows for "chunking" of data, so that these smaller chunks can be reused across various areas of the site. In the hands of competent .NET and web developers, Sitecore is an amazing platform.

**Pros:**

- Full marketing platform
- Engagement focused
- High scalability
- Enterprise level
- Reduced training time

### 2. What are the cons of continuing to utilize Sitecore as our WCM solution?

Sitecore is probably too much for a company that just needs a simple website with a few pages. If your pages are not changing frequently and you don't need automated integration to other systems or processes, Sitecore may not be the best fit.

**Cons:**

- Developer community is still evolving and growing
- Learning curve for some operations (content editor or developer) can be steep
- Only via partners
- Licensing model costs

## 3. What are the pros of migrating to the Sitecore on Azure PaaS solution?

Sitecore Azure provides:

- Extreme scalability, simplicity, and stability.
- A highly available infrastructure with 99.95% uptime with Microsoft Azure's service licensing agreement (SLA): http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/legal/sla.
  Note: you must have two or more instances deployed in the same availability set to qualify for guaranteed 99.95% of external connectivity.
- Significantly reduced costs and time required to deploy your solution to a new server.
- Greater savings on the cost and time required to provide geographically distributed load balancing.
- Reduced redundancy between geographies for performance, as well as disaster preparedness.
- Reduced cost and time required to adjust server capacity to meet the expected load.
- Automation of most of the process of migrating a website to Microsoft Azure.

### 4. What are the cons of migrating to the Sitecore on Azure PaaS solution?

- Lack of full control over the Web Role and SQL Database server configuration and additional software.

### References:

- https://www.cmsbestpractices.com/choosing-the-right-hosting-option-for-sitecore/
- https://www.trustradius.com/reviews/sitecore-web-content-management-2014-02-20-12-11-09
- https://doc.sitecore.net/cloud/azure/getting_started_with_sitecore_azure